# Can I use "uppercaseString" in an app targeting 8.0? Is it safe pre iOS 8.3?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the built in string method `uppercaseString`, like this:

```
let capitalLetters = myString.uppercaseString
```

The documentation tells this for availability:

> iOS (8.3 and later)

However, Xcode is not giving a compiler error, with the `if #available` recommendation, i.e:

```
if #available(iOS 8.3, *) {

} else {

}
```

My question is simple. Can I use this method in an app targeting 8.0? I cannot test it on a device with this version because I don't have one. And the simulator I have is 8.4.

Comment: yes, it will work as uppercaseString is available above 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's documentation:

> var uppercaseString: String { get }
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/uppercaseString

Sometimes xcode shows you wrong availability versions (since swift came out). If sometimes you aren't sure about the availability - check it online.

PS: You can download simulators for which version you want

Comment: Xcode is like a mentally challenged brother. You love it and accept it's flaws, and hope it will improve in the future.